# Installing earth engine on Ubuntu

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to install Earth Engine API on Python on Ubuntu 18.04. I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 installed on my system, and I install Earth Engine using both pip and pip3 as instructed (installing google-api-python-client, oauth2client, and earthengine-api) without any problem. But I get errors on both 2.7 and 3.6:

On Python 2.7, "import ee" works but "ee.Initialize()" returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Initialize'
```

On Python 3.6, "import ee" doesn't work and return this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/sshahhey/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ee/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .main import main
  File "/home/sshahhey/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ee/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    import StringIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'StringIO'
```

Any help? I am particularly interested in solving the problem for Python 3.

Comment: It looks like maybe your preference is to install via pip(3), but out of curiosity, does it work if you install via conda (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/earthengine-api)? If you don't use conda, or are not interested, no worries.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I fixed it.

Comment: Try to work with x64 python but i am getting problems. Then I switch to the 32 bit version. and I don't generate any problem.
check the version and architecture of the python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your system has a Python package called `ee` which **is not the Earth Engine API**. I say this because the Python 3 traceback specifies a file named `ee/main.py`, which does not exist and never has. This would also explain why `ee.Initialize()` was not found in the other case.

I'd recommend going into `/home/sshahhey/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ee/` and browsing the code there to see what other package it might be. If it's not something you need, then you can just delete that `ee/`. If it is something you need for another purpose, you can use **virtualenv** to manage installations of conflicting libraries.

Answer (score 4):

Following up on Kevin's answer:

I had this same issue, but the state of my `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ee` looked the same as that of my coworker, whose **Earth Engine API** was working fine. The issue is that there are 2 `pip` packages which write to the same directory:

- `earthengine-api:`

  - this is the package you want
  - writes the **Earth Engine** library to `site-packages/ee`
- `ee:`

  - Unrelated to EE, just a wrapper for `dd`
  - writes a `main.py` and `__init__.py` to `site-packages/ee`

The ***only difference*** between our two setups was the order in which we installed those packages. For me, installing `ee` second overwrote the `__init__.py` file, which prevented the `ee` module from importing the library contents. The fix was to completely clear out the directory and related `dist-info` dir, and start over:

1. `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ee`
2. `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/earthengine_api-0.1.182.dist-info`
3. `sudo pip install earthengine_api`